# Simulated Metrics "Orientation" dropdown missing

Tags: xcode, xcode8-beta3

The Simulated Metrics menu in the Attributes Inspector is missing the Orientation dropdown option in xCode 8.0 beta 3.

[image: Example]

I have the root view controller selected. The option is unavailable for any view.

Answer (score 6):

The Orientation option has been removed. You may access devices by size and orientation at the bottom of the Standard Editor View. This is not reflected in the Xcode documentation.

[image: Moved]